# Jquery Ajax does not calling action in different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I m in a situation where i need to call a action method of different controller

I mean I am currently in controller 'Wk' action -History's 
On this view when i click any link then an ajax call will call the action method of different controller.
But the ajax call calls the action method of the same controller.

the jquery is -

```
$.get("History/20/5/2", function (data) {
                $("div#dShow").html(data);
                $("div#dShow").dialog({
                    opacity: 0,
                    height: 700,
                    width: '1024px',
                    show: 'blind',
                    hide: 'blind'
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 3000, function () {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it what action to call on the history controller:

```
$.get("History/Index/20/5/2", function (data) {
            $("div#dShow").html(data);
            $("div#dShow").dialog({
                opacity: 0,
                height: 700,
                width: '1024px',
                show: 'blind',
                hide: 'blind'
            }).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 3000, function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });
```

Comment: here history is my controller name

Comment: @user1006544 So what is the action name? 20?

Comment: Here action name is Index so I think it dosent need to mention the index thats y i havent mentioned the action

Comment: Unless you have a very specific route set up for this exact situation you will need to specify the action name as well. Otherwise mvc cannot work out which controller you want. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: I have changed that but it is not calling the action of History Controller